# How do I check if the current url or path is equal to a certain link and if not, append a forward slash to the href in the nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a JavaScript and jQuery newby and have some issues with page scroll being directed from different page. The work is being done in WordPress PHP. I am currently using page-scroll where the href=#id and I changed it to href=/#id where the slash allows for the directing properly. The issue is if I am on the current page of home. the forward slash now jumps rather than page-scrolls. My thinking is leave the href=#id without the slash and have it check if the current url != to home, then append a forward slash to href. Help is genuinely appreciated!

> This allows for page scroll from current page and doesn't direct from Pricing & Services page

```
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#howitworks">How It Works</a></li>
```

> Adding the "/" allows for directing from Pricing& Services page however it jumps if I am on the homepage. I want it to jump if I am not on the homepage. I would like for it to smooth scroll on current page.

```
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="/#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
```

> Page I am directing from.

```
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="pricing-services">Pricing & Services</a></li>
```

This is the javascript code I am using which requires the Jquery Easing plugin

```
    $(function() {
      $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
       var $anchor = $(this);
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-50
       }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
       event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Unsure why this is `PHP` tagged. What is it you want to have done? Do you have more examples of what you're doing so far?

Comment: @Twisty not to mention the `CSS` tag...

Comment: I removed those tags, however PHP did solve my issue. I used a different header.

Answer (score 1):

To get current url you can use `window.location.pathname` :

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var add = '';
```

Check if `"home"` is in url. `indexOf` returns -1 if it doesnt find anything. Else it return the position of the first occurance

```
if(path.indexOf("home") == -1){   
    add = '/';
}
```

Then add the slash to href like this:

```
var href = $('.page-scroll').attr('href');
$('.page-scroll').attr('href',add+href);
```

Comment: Maybe `var path = $(location).attr('href');` and `$(location).attr('href', add+path);` is more convenient (jQuery style).

Comment: I will read a little bit more into JS and try this solution as well. Thank you guys for even looking and I will give it a try and learn from this solution!

Comment: @AlexHuang ok let me know if it worked for you. I think that you wanted exactly what i answered you - check if the homepage is url and add slash. So i think i should be right.

Answer (score 0):

You could change all the the `/#`s to `#`, and give every page a base tag, besides the home page:

```
<head>
  <base href='./' />
</head>
```

Alternatively, remove all of the `/#`s so they're just `#` and put the following JavaScript on an external `.js` page.

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
var doc = document, loc = location;
if(pre)pre();
function pageHashRedirect(homePageURL){
  var url = loc.protocol.replace(/:$/, '')+'://'+loc.hostname+'/'+loc.pathname.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, ''), bs;
  if(!url.match(new RegExp('^'+homePageURL.replace(/\/$/, '')+'$', 'i'))){
    if(!doc.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]){
      bs = doc.createElement('base'); doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(bs);
    }
    else{
      bs = doc.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
    }
    bs.href = './';
  }
}
pageHashRedirect('homePageURLwithoutGetAndHashTag.extHERE');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out more in depth. I have a temporary fix using PHP with an alternative header on certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

This framework is in PHP, so a quick fix I found was to use another custom header for certain pages that had the forward slash and on the homepage without it. Thank you all. I'm sure if this was done in node.js, the correct fix wouldn't be the PHP method.